# Add tables from access database to QGIS

Tags: qgis, database, ms-access

There are some similar question here, but nothing worked for me. So I have a database that has the ending `.mdb` which to my knowledge is some kind of Microsoft access database. But I also tried it with a test-database that has the standard `.accdb`-ending and did not manage to make it work.

I did the following: I clicked on `Layer --> addd Layer --> add Vector Layer`. Then I select database and `type=ODBC` and opening the connection dialog this appears:

[image]

And I'm not really sure what to enter here. I tried several thigs and none of them did work for me. So basically I guessed that I can name it as I want to name it. And the most important part is the `Database`-field. However, when I put the path to the database in there I always get the error:

```
Connection failed - Check settings and try again.

Extended error information:
Unable to initialize ODBC connection to DSN for C
```

Answer (score 3):

You are half way there. In windows you will need to setup the ODBC connection to the database file though windows built in odbc manager. If it's an access database you may need to install the free ms access database engine. If you have ms office it might already be installed. Once you have done that the connection should work in qgis.

Comment: thanks a lot!! Do you know if there is any way to do this under linux as well?

Comment: Not a big linux user but have a look here: http://cdn.cdata.com/help/DCC/odbc/

Comment: thanks a lot:) really appreciated